# tinymce-react - how to hide dotted line in read-only mode

Tags: html, reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-5

I have a question regarding `tinymce-react`. I am using tinymce in my react project to preview html content.

---

Below is my editor setting:

```
<Editor
 value={templateDetails.content}
 init={{
   toolbar: false,
   menubar: false,
   height: 400,
   setup(editor) {
     editor.setMode('readonly');
   },
 }}
/>
```

The view I am getting:

[image: view]

I would like to hide the dotted lines as shown in the picture. I have gone through the [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/) on the official website, but I still couldn't find the configuration to hide the lines. Can anyone point out what am I missing here?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, if you're wanting to preview HTML content, TinyMCE may not be the best solution for this. It's HTML, so you can place the content within a separate div element or an iframe to preview the content. If you're wanting to edit the HTML content, then TinyMCE is the way to go. Can you please elaborate a bit further on your intentions with the HTML content?

Comment: Hi @DallasClark, I am developing an email template editing feature for my project. There is a section where users are able to preview the email template from the list which they have created earlier. So, I decided to use TinyMCE for that purpose to show the email content.

Comment: If you're wanting to show a preview of the email template, I would suggest using an iframe element. Otherwise you're bringing in an editor when no editing is required, creating unnecessary overhead. Additionally, as you have found, the editor is not designed for previewing content.

Comment: You are right. There is no benefit to using an editor just for the sake of previewing content. I will consider replacing it with an iframe element. Really appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dashed borders on tables is to indicate where the hidden boundaries of the element is. This is really useful for resizing tables, columns and rows.

If you're really wanting to hide the borders, you can override the CSS during initialisation with the following configuration:

```
content_style: '.mce-item-table, .mce-item-table td {border: none;}'
```

This will hide the dashed table border and table-cell borders.

More details on how to customise the appearance of the content within the editor is available on [Tiny's Documentation website](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_style).

Additionally, I have created a [Tiny fiddle to demonstrate](https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/8qhaab).